press F1 to boot after restart (920-fan command 2 pin connector from power supply not connected)
setup: old HP d530 SFF(DK907A) Pentium4, running Fedora 8, power supply 500W HPQ-500BR-H12S, HP P6B580 motherboard (I will attach some photos as well)
problem: I have to press F1 to boot after PC restart, and I need to make it independent from human interaction, because I am not always near that PC. The message is "920-Fan Command 2 Pin Connector from Power Supply Not Connected"
Any ideas on what I could do so that I don't always have to press F1? thank you so much!!






I'm guessing the 'original' PSU wasn't standard ATX - and had a separate header its expecting. I wonder if there's something in the bios that might let you turn off halting on errors?

https://youtu.be/q6sHkUNVLFU indicates there's a fan on the PSU, and I'm almost certain there's a seperate 2 pin from that to a fan header . https://superuser.com/questions/63431/hp-d530-startup-error-512-chassis-fan-not-detected is a similar question that indicates these systems get a little cranky when fans are missing.

Typically there's an option in your bios which allows you to chose wether to halt or not on errors.
